# Zipping a file with Yazl using Buffers

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I've been tasked with creating a zip (from a buffer) using [yazl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yazl). I've never used a library quite like this before.

**Usage (from documentation)**

```
var yazl = require("yazl");

var zipfile = new yazl.ZipFile();
zipfile.addFile("file1.txt", "file1.txt");
// (add only files, not directories)
zipfile.addFile("path/to/file.txt", "path/in/zipfile.txt");
// pipe() can be called any time after the constructor
zipfile.outputStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("output.zip")).on("close", function() {
  console.log("done");
});
// alternate apis for adding files:
zipfile.addReadStream(process.stdin, "stdin.txt");
zipfile.addBuffer(Buffer.from("hello"), "hello.txt");
// call end() after all the files have been added
zipfile.end();
```

**My example code**

```
var zipfile = new yazl.ZipFile();
// just sanity checking (should already be utf8)
let encodedXml = utf8.encode(req.body.xml);

zipfile.addBuffer(
    Buffer.from(encodedXml),
    EPRICER_FILENAME
);

zipfile.end();
```

I'm not sure where the zip even is at this point - how do I get to the buffer I've made? How can I see my zip's data?

Any help would be *really* appreciated,

Thanks,
Ollie

Comment: Look for `outputStream` in the documentation.

Comment: Hi there :) thanks for the response, I can't quite figure out how the outputStream is supposed to work. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be piping in, or how I access the file once I'm there :/

Comment: You pipe *out* of the output stream. That stream will be the contents of the zip file, and so you pipe that into a writer to send it wherever you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks again :) but I think this comment has made me even more confused! Sorry, I'm very new to this sort of thing. 

Instead of passing a file that get's written to (in the pipe), I just want to pass _something_ to it. The place where where file is written to in `fs.createWriteStream()` would need to be a variable/in memory.

I've looked at the npm library 'stream-buffers' but I'm still quite unsure on how to get it hooked up.